# Use the Button Name for the form button value (Python / Flask)

Tags: python, html, flask, form-submit

I've tried searching and havent had much luck so reaching out for some guidance please.

I have a Python app using flask and SQLite.  The problem I have run into is that I would like to present a differnt number of buttons on a web page based on the number of races over the previous week.  One week it could be 5 races and another week it could be 2 races.  Here is an example image:

[image]

I have no issue getting the data to the webservice.  Where it becomes difficult is that I use a dictionary to build the number of buttons available for that week on the webpage and I only have a single submit button option for a mutiple buttons which mean I am unable to know which button the user selected.

**HTML Code**

```
{% for key in raceReRun %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" name="raceLocationButton" value="button_value">{{ key['race_location'] }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to know which button was clicked?  Remember that one week it could be 2 buttons and another week it could be 7 buttons and the names changes to a different location.

Hope that makes sense and thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you just assign the value a variable from the loop? Or add something like this to your loop?

```
{% for key in raceReRun %}
i = 0
i += 1
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary-btn-sm" name="raceLocationButton" value=i}{{ key['race_location'] }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you ... I solved it by doing hte following:
     
 `<div class="input-group mb-3">

      {% for key in range(raceReRun| length) %}



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" name="raceLocationButton" value={{key}}>{{ raceReRun[key]['race_location'] }}</button>

  
      {% endfor %}
      </div>`